# javascript: how would I convert this with destructuring?

Tags: javascript

I am looping through and overriding `newNotification` right now.  I am trying to rewrite this block to make use of destructuring.  This is the block of code:

```
  let newNotification;
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      newNotificaton = await apiEndpoint(
        files[i].name,
        JSON.stringify(files[i].read.toJSON()),
      );
  }

  return newNotification.nameToUse;
```

I tried to do the following but the end result doesn't behave the same:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      let { nameToUse } = await apiEndpoint(
        files[i].name,
        JSON.stringify(files[i].read.toJSON()),
      );
  }

  return nameToUse;
```

Comment: What does `apiEndpoint` return?

Comment: an object with `nameToUse` as a field

Comment: Why do you call it multiple times and permanently override the result of the previous ones?

Comment: `let` declarations are block scoped, so `nameToUse` will not be visible outside the `for` loop. Simply declare it outside exactly like you did with `let newNotification` and remove the `let` from inside the loop. Then it will be equivalent (as long as the result from `apiEndpoint()` isn't `null` or `undefined`).

Comment: @VLAZ But then... what's the point of even having a loop if the variable is only used at the end, with the final value? **Edit**: oh, Mka's comment below explains it all

Comment: @GuerricP each call adds something but the endpoint always returns the total so the last one is all I need.

Comment: @blex ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ it's just how to make an equivalent code. Not instructions for how the code to make sense.

Comment: @VLAZ if I declare `let nameToUse;` outside of the block and then do `{ nameToUse } = await apiEndpoint()`, my console says "declaration or statement expected" and points to the `=` sign

Comment: @Mka38jdj oh, right - surround the assignment in round brackets `({nameToUse} = await /* ... */)` otherwise the `{}` is interpreted as a code block instead of destructuring.